# SQL for ordering an alphanumeric string by the numeric part

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a MySQL tablewith a VARCHAR column containing values as follows:

```
abc-1
abc-2
abc-10
...etc.
```

Is there any way to sort it in MySQL by the numeric part in the order:

```
abc-1
abc-2
```

instead of

```
abc-1
abc-10
abc-2
```

?

*Clarification of data values*

Typical values are mir-1, mir-14, mir-193, with the highest being mir-4987. To simplify things, let's assume all begin with ‘mir-’ (I can deal with the few exceptions by hand).

Comment: Please show a sample of data which shows the complete range of possible values.  For instance, does every value begin with `abc`?

Comment: Depending on the actual format of the data, you may want to fix this at insertion-time, by analyzing the contents at that point and extract the numeric value into a separate column or otherwise derive and store a sort key. This to prevent executing queries that can't benefit from indexes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen — Have done.

Comment: If only the numeric part matters you can cast the value: `order by col+0` or `order by cast(col as unsigned)`. But you'll get a truncating warning.

Comment: Curious why at least two people marked this question down. Searched to check it hadn't been asked before, appropriate to StackOverflow, real world problem, not obvious to non-expert and turns out it has an answer.

Comment: Seriously, you think this question hasn't been asked before?

Comment: @Strawberry — Well why wasn't it marked as a duplicate then instead of just marking it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your column can contain `abc-1` or other values too like these only such as `defg-12`
and you want to order `abc` ones first and the others ones after.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    your_table
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(t, '-', 1) , CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t, '-', - 1) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: That worked fine after I had followed MySQL's advice that 't' should be substituted by the field name ;-). Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can also add 1 or 2 virtual columns that calculates your string and integer automatic and order it direct to the int. then you can also use a index on this column.

to add the virtual columns use a query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
ADD s1 VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(t, '-',  1)) STORED,
ADD i1 INT(11)     GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(t, '-', -1)) STORED;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM your_table;
+----+--------+
| id | t      |
+----+--------+
|  1 | abc-2  |
|  2 | abc-21 |
|  3 | abc-32 |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE your_table
    -> ADD s1 VARCHAR(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(t, '-',  1)) STORED,
    -> ADD i1 INT(11)     GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(t, '-', -1)) STORED;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0,02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM your_table;
+----+--------+------+------+
| id | t      | s1   | i1   |
+----+--------+------+------+
|  1 | abc-2  | abc  |    2 |
|  2 | abc-21 | abc  |   21 |
|  3 | abc-32 | abc  |   32 |
+----+--------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> insert into your_table (id,t) VALUES(4,'abc-9876');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM your_table;
+----+----------+------+------+
| id | t        | s1   | i1   |
+----+----------+------+------+
|  1 | abc-2    | abc  |    2 |
|  2 | abc-21   | abc  |   21 |
|  3 | abc-32   | abc  |   32 |
|  4 | abc-9876 | abc  | 9876 |
+----+----------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE your_table set t='abc-2211' where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM your_table;
+----+----------+------+------+
| id | t        | s1   | i1   |
+----+----------+------+------+
|  1 | abc-2211 | abc  | 2211 |
|  2 | abc-21   | abc  |   21 |
|  3 | abc-32   | abc  |   32 |
|  4 | abc-9876 | abc  | 9876 |
+----+----------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```